# ignore character within single quotes regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a colon that is not inside single quotes but outside.

Say:

```
SELECT :1 FROM Table
'not this colon : inside single quotes'
```

It should only match the colon outside the single quotes.

Comment: try `:(?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'])*$)`

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
:(?=((?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK6oB1/1)